# 'xterm-new': unknown terminal type

Tags: ssh, ncurses, iterm, iterm2

Replicating the error:

1. I am using iTerm2 on Macbook (OS X Yosemite)
2. I ssh into a remote instance and tried to run the `clear` command and this error is shown:

   'xterm-new': unknown terminal type.
3. Not only for the `clear` command but the same error is displayed for several other commands and the command does not execute as expected.
4. The error occurs only when I use iTerm2 and not when I use the default Mac Terminal. So I am guessing this problem has something to do with iTerm2 and not the virtual machine.

How can I solve this problem with iTerm2?

Comment: There should be a setting "Report Terminmal Type" under "Terminal" in the preferences. Try setting this to "xterm-256color" and check if the "TERM" environment variable is set to "xterm-256color" (`echo $TERM`) if it isn't do so. (`export TERM=xterm-256color`)

Comment: @mikyra Wow, that solves my problem. I just had to set TERM=xterm-256color. Didn't have to change anything in the preferences and couldn't even find the "Report Terminal Type" option. I wonder why xterm-256color works and xterm-new creates problems.

Comment: the terminal type xterm-new isn't known in the terminfo database on the machine you are logging in. (`man terminfo` to learn more about it)

Comment: That's odd, since `xterm-new` was added to ncurses in mid-1998, while `xterm-256color` was introduced over a year later.  Both appear in the late-2008 version of ncurses provided by Apple on my older Mac.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [mikyra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2056411/mikyra) pointed out in the comments above, setting the environment variable TERM=xterm-256color solves the problem.

To summarize:

```
# Run the following commands on the local machine's bash prompt
echo "export TERM=xterm-256color" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

`ssh` into remote machine and run the commands you like. The same xterm-new error should not occur now.

Comment: For me i used these commands in the remote machine and it worked